# Why does GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity return null even when I know the group exists?

Tags: c#, active-directory

Why would

```
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(getPrincipalContext(), 
                                                         "TEST_DESTINATION_GRP");
```

return `null`? I know for a fact that `TEST_DESTINATION_GRP` exists under the groups organizational unit.

My code:

```
private void addUserToGroup(string userName, string groupName)
{
    try
    {
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(getPrincipalContext(), IdentityType.SamAccountName, "jcolon");
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(getPrincipalContext(), "TEST_DESTINATION_GRP");
        //just to show that I can access AD            
        ArrayList x = getUserGroups(userName);

        foreach (var xy in x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xy);
        }//I can access AD FINE

        if (group == null)
        { Console.WriteLine("Wtf!"); }
        Console.WriteLine(user); 
        Console.WriteLine(group + "empty why!!!!");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        //log e
    }
}

private PrincipalContext getPrincipalContext()
{
    PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, sDomain,sDefaultOU);          
    return oPrincipalContext;
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Domain Users
GRP_ADMIN_SERVER
GRP_PROG_III
CTXXA-FlexUser
CTXXA-Users
Wtf
Abanico, Elnora@MSH
empty why!!!!
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What are the values in `sDomain` and `sDefaultOU` in your `getPrincipalContext` method??

I would try the following steps:

1. Construct your `PrincipalContext` without any domain or OU name - in that case, your default domain and its top-level node will be used:

   ```
   PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
   ```

   Search now - does it find your group you're looking for??
2. Check to make sure the domain and `sDefaultOU` values are correct - if you connect your principal context to one OU, you cannot search in another OU, obviuosly (unless that's a child-OU of the OU you're connecting to).